# What's the best way to parse a packet data in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm transcoding a Delphi App to C++ and got a problem to get the correct way to do the cases of packet headers in C++.

The Headers Comes as "Dword" in a UCHAR buf and i dont want make like: if (packet[0] == 0xFF && packet[1] == 0xFF...);

Ex: Delphi Working with switch case:

```
              case PDword(@Packet[6])^ of
                $68FB0200:
                  begin
                     //Dword match correctly
                  End;
              end;
```

is there a way to do the same in C++ like the Delphi Example?

Already checked for some methds but ever fails the comparsion.

```
UCHAR               *Packet ;
Packet = ParsePacket(buf->Buf, buf->Size);
// The ParsePacket Returns FB 00 00 00 78 00 01 F3 02 FD

DWORD Op1 = 0x01F302FD;
DWORD *p_dw = (DWORD*) Packet[6];
if (p_dw == Op1)
{
 //Dword never match...
}
```

Comment: The syntax you're after would be either `(DWORD*)(Packet+6)` or `(DWORD*)&(Packet[6])`.  Note, however, that the authors of the Standard left support for such constructs as a Quality of Implementation outside their jurisdiction, the maintainers of clang and gcc regard as "broken" any code which the Standard wouldn't require implementations to process usefully, and such code will only work on those compilers if one uses the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag.

Comment: Clarification: such a program would have _undefined behaviour_ and shouldn't be written much less relied upon (supercat famously refuses to accept the existence of UB)

Comment: @supercat: `UCHAR` is almost certainly a narrow character type, which is assumed to alias other types.  Alignment on the other hand....

Comment: @BenVoigt That only works in one direction. You can alias a `DWORD*` and a `char*`, in order to observe the `char`s making up a `DWORD`. You cannot do the opposite: you can't observe a non-existent `DWORD` that isn't actually in a bunch of `char`s.

Comment: @supercat The cool thing is that depending on undefined behavior in the standard is unnecessary. You can just write things so that you don't care what the implementation--defined behavior is (if any). As to why you insist on doing things the non-portable way - I wouldn't know. But you clearly don't need to do it that way. So at that point it's just some weird idée fixe. It actually complicates matters, not makes them simple as you apparently insist.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Until we see the insides of `ParsePacket`, it might actually have created an array of `DWORD` and returned a `UCHAR*` pointing to some element of that array (legal).  Unless the compiler can prove otherwise, it has to assume you are completing a roundtrip back to the original pointer type, which is 100% legal.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is possible, yes. Seems unlikely, though. Usually we traffic in bytes over a network, and there seems little reason for `DWORD`s to have been constructed during that phase. Regardless of what the compiler can prove, you cannot pretend an object exists if it doesn't. Better write safe and robust code.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: Under a sufficiently obtuse, but nonetheless literally correct, reading of the C Standard, an implementation could process 99% of non-contrived C programs in arbitrary meaningless fashion and still be "conforming.  Further, if one were to treat as UB all actions which the Standard would define as equivalent to actions that clang and gcc treat as UB, large parts of the language would be useless.  Finally, if the vast majority of compilers can be configured to process a construct meaningfully, how "non-portable" is it, really?

Comment: @supercat You're suggesting to ignore the most basic of aliasing rules and alignment requirements that modern optimizers routinely depend on: you have no argument here. Such code indeed produces garbage output when compiled, and it takes no obtuse reading of anything. I'm fixing such code in other people's projects with regularity, usually after they have spent an inordinate amount of time unwittingly heeding advice such as your and then pull their hair out because stuff's broken. I mean: yes, it is certainly some form of job security, but I'd rather deal with cooler things, you know.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: Large parts of the language would be useless if there were no allowance for the possibility than an lvalue derived from a pointer or lvalue of that other type might access an object of that type.  For example, `someStruct.intArray[i]` woudl be UB because `int` is not among the types that may be used to access a structure type.  The Standard only attempts to specify when aliasing must be accounted for *in cases where no derivation is visible*; the question of when to recognize derivation has always been a Quality of Implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: If you want to argue that the name C no longer refers to a language that's as powerful as the one the C89 Standard was written to describe, and which the authors of the Standard recognized as being useful as a "high-level assembler" (a usage they expressly wished not to preclude), or if you want to argue that C++ is no longer intended to be capable of everything that can be done in that language, fine.  I'd love to see a split between gcc-c and a standardized dialect that supports low-level constructs.  Stop denying the existence or usefulness of the latter, though.

Comment: I don't know what sort of argument you have when I'm literally fixing these problems that cause failures in production every other month it seems. You can of course take your argument to people willing to spend consulting rates for me to fix their code, but you may find having a hard time to convince them that your beliefs trump their downtime (those are always post-mortem fixes, mind you). I truly can't fathom what you're after here. Of course you can think I'm just lying to you out of some high-grounded-spite. Alas, I have no time for such nonsense.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: Can you offer any evidence in the Rationale to suggest that the Committee did not intend that implementations *intended to be suitable for low-level programming* not accommodate constructs like the use of `*(uint32*)somePointerType = someValue;` to alter a value of `somePointerType`'s target type in situations where that would help a programmer accomplish what needed to be done?

Comment: I have no such evidence. I just fix broken code written with the assumptions you partially espouse. In other words:  If you believe the Earth is flat and 6000 years old, try and make some money out of it (other than just from preaching it). I mean, clearly some entirely misguided people pay to fix code written using flat-young-Earth beliefs. I admit that there's lots of stupid spending in the world of corporate headless chickens, but it seems like a big stretch that imaginary problems would cause downtime, magically resolved by imaginary fixes. I don't know what else to say anymore about it.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: The authors of the Standard have expressly said that they did not wish to demean code that is useful but non-portable.  Clang and gcc have adopted a broken aliasing model which fits neither the letter nor spirit of the C Standard, and for which I am unaware of any full and complete characterization that would identify all cases that they don't support reliably, but still support most of the language.  They have spread the religion that code which doesn't fit their abstraction model is "broken", but such a view was not shared by the C89 Committee.

Comment: @supercat I am in full agreement about it being sensible not to wish to demean code that is useful but non-portable. Yet there are clearly compiler implementers that feel empowered to do what the standard allows them to, rather than what the authors of the standard wish for. Given that this leads to tricky bugs in production code, it is prudent to warn others that in spite of what the authors may preach, the reality-as-implemented begs to differ. Caveat emptor. Objects in the mirror may appear denormalized.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: I believe I made clear the need to use `-fno-strict-aliasing` when using such constructs.  Unfortunately, a lot of people have no idea of the extent to which the language processed by clang and gcc has diverged from the language the Standards were written to describe.  A principle that should be self-obvious is that in cases where parts of the Standard and an implementation's documentation define a behavior, but other parts characterize it as UB, an implementation intended for particular purposes should give priority to the behavioral specs when useful for those pruposes.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: A related principle is that an "optimizer" that makes it harder to accomplish what needs to be done isn't really an optimizer.  The authors of the Standard made no attempt to judge what optimizers should or shouldn't do, since they recognized that in order to successfully sell their products, compiler writers would need to know and respect their customers' needs better than the Committee ever could.  They failed to anticipate that freely distributable tools need not be very good to kill the market for quality ones.

Comment: @supercat I'm of the mind that compatible derivatives of C are basically on life support at this point due to how the standard has been written. There's lots of potential for a "niche" closed-source language to emerge for at embedded applications, that offers a superficially similar language without most of the cruft, and without the absurdly complex post-parsing stage that C++ necessitates. Nobody will do much in the way of good business with "straight" C/C++ tooling since it'd take an absurd effort to be better than what's out there. I'd pay good money for a modern C-like toolset.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: What's needed is for someone with clout to establish a new standard which formally recognizes constructs that implementations should support when practical, but which implementations may instead document (in both human-readable and macro-testable ways) that they do not support.  The choice of what constructs to support constructs would be a quality-of-implementation issue, and the choice of what constructs to require would be a portability issue, but the documentation of non-supported constructs (for implementatiosn) or needed constructs (for programs) would be required.

Comment: @supercat: `*(uint32*)somePointerType = someValue;` has *always* been broken on *most* platforms for the purpose envisioned in the question, so your idea that this is a valid "high-level assembler" construct is already contrary to reality.  Besides, C has a mechanism for saying "do this, don't try to optimize what you think I mean" which in your example would be `*(uint32 volatile *)somePointerType = someValue;`  Use of C as high-level assembler will need liberal use of `volatile`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: On most platforms, its "broken-ness" would depend upon whether alignment meets platform requirements and platform endianness meets code requirements.  Even when writing code for 8-bit systems, I generally lay out my data to ensure that any 16- or 32-bit quantities I will want to work with will end up at aligned offsets within a relevant containing structure.  This particular poster's example wouldn't be portable to something like a Cortex-M0 unless the buffer started at offset 4N+2 within a word-aligned structure, but should work fine on little-endian platforms which...

Comment: ...can load/store 32-bit values with arbitrary alignment.  If the authors of the Standard wanted to preclude such constructs even when targeting known platforms, why does their Rationale include an example which is contrived to show a situation where type punning would be very unlikely to be useful on any platform?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: Passing thought: if type punning were so useless as some people claim, I wonder why so many people would be asking about it here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the portable C (and C++) way is:

```
DWORD const Op1 = 0x01F302FD;
if (0 == memcmp(Packet + 6, &Op1, sizeof Op1)) { ... }
```

Note that we haven't tried to access the bytes at `Packet+6` as a 32-bit quantity... they're likely to be misaligned for that.  We're just asking whether the same sequence of 4 bytes exists there as exist in `Op1`.

Comment: The syntax may look a bit atrocious, but the compiler can optimize that really well.  (It's probably an intrinsic, and not a function.)

Comment: @Eljay Even better: modern compilers can treat `memcmp` as if it was a `constexpr` function in some cases. They won't let you use it where `constexpr` is required, but can indeed transform the enclosing function into a constexpr one and evaluate it at compile time. One can of course argue that this is an absurdly bad design based on aesthetics alone, but that's what the C baggage brought us :/

Comment: The example works fine to my simple problem, just paying atention to the endian.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious issue with `DWORD *p_dw = (DWORD*) Packet[6]` is that you take a value as an address. You probably meant `DWORD *p_dw = (DWORD*)&(Packet[6])`.

Note, however, that you get additional troubles for two reasons:

First, alignment could be wrong such that the pointer received is not a valid address to be taken for dereferencing a DWORD. This is undefined behaviour then.

Second, you depend on a specific endianess.

To overcome the first issue, you could use `memcpy`:

```
DWORD Op2 = 0;
memcpy(&Op2,Packet+6,sizeof(Op2));
```

To overcome both the first and the second issue, you'll need to sum the bytes on your own, e.g.:

```
DWORD Op2 = Packet[6]<<24 | Packet[7]<<16 | Packet[8]<<8 | Packet[9]
```